# How to call an HTML css style in a computed text field

Tags: html, css, xpages

As a part of a Bootstrap table I have the following code:

```
<xp:text escape="false"
    id="tableRowstart" >
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if (rIndex % 2){
    return "<tr style='background-color:#e6e6e6'><td>"
}else{
    return "<tr style='background-color:#fbfbfb'><td>"}}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

this is part of a repeat control and rIndex is the repeat index value. The above code works fine, but I want to use it in a css. So I added these lines to my css:

```
.oddLineBackground {background-color:#e6e6e6 ;}
.evenLineBackground {background-color:#fbfbfb ;}
```

If I modify my code to use the css as follows:

```
<xp:text escape="false"
    id="tableRowstart" >
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if (rIndex % 2){
    return "<tr style='oddLineBackground'><td>"
}else{
    return "<tr style='evenLineBackground'><td>"}}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

The line colors do not change, they display with no style applied. I can apply the oddLineBackground and evenLineBackground to a panel or ??? directly from the style picker and they display correctly but when I compute them they don't seem to compute correctly. I'm guessing that it is something in my syntax, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<tr style='oddLineBackground'>
```

to this:

```
<tr class='oddLineBackground'>
```